# syslog-ng show errors every time start

Tags: freebsd, syslog-ng

everyone! After i install syslog-ng in my freebsd9.1 and use it for my log systerm. Every time i start it there display an error:

```
Error opening plugin module; module='afuser', error='/usr/local/lib/syslog-ng/libafuser.so: Undefined symbol "endutent"'
```

And this is my config file.

```
  #############################################################################
  # Default syslog-ng.conf file which collects all local logs into a
  # single file called /var/log/messages.
  #
  @version: 3.4

  source s_net { 
   udp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(514));

   };

    filter firewallfilter {
     program("haproxy");

    };

   template m_template {
   template("$MSGONLY\n");
   template_escape(no);
    };

    destination d_net_secure {
         file("/weblog/haproxy/$YEAR/$MONTH.$DAY/${R_HOUR}$(/ ${R_MIN} 5).log"                                           
         template(m_template) create_dirs(yes));
        };

    log {
         source(s_net);
         filter (firewallfilter);
         destination(d_net_secure);
    };
```

my base systerm info:

```
   FreeBSD 9.1-BETA1
     syslog-ng 3.4.0alpha3
   Installer-Version: 3.4.0alpha3
    Revision: ssh+git://bazsi@git.balabit//var/scm/git/syslog-ng/syslog-ng-ose--     mainline--3.4#master#709ab1252920063e6d4d0d610ad5c1ee5ebdfb75
      Compile-Date: Jul 27 2012 15:30:21
      Available-Modules: afsocket,afsocket-notls,afsocket-                         tls,afsql,affile,afprog,afmongodb,csvparser,confgen,syslogformat,basicfuncs,dbparser,tfuuid
      Enable-Debug: on
      Enable-GProf: off
      Enable-Memtrace: off
      Enable-IPv6: off
     Enable-Spoof-Source: off
      Enable-TCP-Wrapper: off
      Enable-Linux-Caps: off
      Enable-Pcre: on
```

I google many times but there was no answer.
Does any one can tell me, What's the wrong with my syslog-ng and my freebsd.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug, one can't use the usertty destination right now. It should be fixed in git: https://github.com/bazsi/syslog-ng-3.4/commit/ee6a3fac72ef72efe0656ef6ed65921720ae3866

Comment: THX, for your answer!